# to fight the urge vs to fight off the urge

Tags: phrasal-verbs

> I was trying to fight off the urge to sneak into the kitchen for something to eat.

I came across a phrasal verb "fight off" and wondered if it would still be correct to leave "off" out and whether it would change the meaning.

> I was trying to fight the urge to sneak into the kitchen for something to eat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they do not mean exactly the same thing. Dropping "*off*" doesn't make it incorrect but there is a nuance of meaning.

> fight something/someone off - would mean "succeed in overcoming (so as to be removed);"
>
> fight something/someone - struggle to overcome;

More to the point, *"fight **off**"* carries a slightly different meaning where ***"off"*** changes the meaning as in:

> finish off - completely defeat something or someone; completely consume food or drink;
>
> finish - to complete something; finish work, homework or something. So if you said
> "I finished off my homework" that would be figurative (though *finish with* is more common), yet it's not
> something I'd see commonly used.

Sometimes different verbs match different nouns.